# About how many lines come up when booting a typical Linux distro?

Tags: logs, startup, dmesg

I'm trying to understand all the text that screams by when my server boots up.  Is that really intended to be human readable?  About how many lines scream by?  Is there a way I can count them?  Is there an overall structure to what screams by (e.g. kernel, hardware recognized, network recognized, overall OS coming up)?

Comment: They get logged to /var/log/dmesg, /var/log/syslog and others depending on which line is the output of what. They're human readable in that way. They're shown on the screen during boot-up, so that if it hangs during boot-up you can tell what went wrong (hopefully).

Comment: It's not for humans, it's for programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking around](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linux%20boot%20log) a little for this answer pointed me to [another Stack Exchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/176165/where-linux-places-the-messages-of-boot).  I tried the files suggested there until I got to `/var/log/boot.log`, which held the relevant information.

```
username@host ~ $ cat /var/log/boot.log
```

So then to count the number of lines output:

```
wc -l /var/log/boot.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the system has started, you can use the `dmesg` command (maybe better `dmesg | less`) to read the kernel ring buffer. This buffer will include the messages during the boot if you use them just after it. Also, you can read `/var/log/boot.log` and `/var/log/messages` (or `/var/log/syslog`, deppending on your Linux distribution).

Comment: dmesg is limited.  I'm trying to count more lines than dmesg can keep a history of.

Comment: Well... dmesg is a ring buffer. But just after your system starts, it should contain all the information you need. Anyway, if you start in text mode, with grubs "noquiet" mode (no graphical boot screen, no boot "loadingbar", etc), and you don't switch to a different virtual terminal (you don't use Alt+FX) you can use Ctrl+PgUp to go up and read all the info that was written on the screen.